# yargs not reading inputs correctly

Tags: javascript, nodemon, yargs

in my apps.js file, I have the following code:

```
const yargs=require('yargs');
const argv=yargs.argv;
console.log('yargs',argv);
```

And when I run the command normally I get:

```
> node app.js read --title="to by"
yargs { _: [ 'read' ],
  help: false,
  version: false,
  title: 'to by',
  '$0': 'app.js' }
```

however when I use nodemon, I get the wrong parameters if there is a space in title:

```
> nodemon app.js read --title="to by"
yargs { _: [ 'read', '"--title=to', 'by"' ],
  help: false,
  version: false,
  '$0': 'app.js' }
```

So the app does not run correctly. WHat is going on here? Thanks

Comment: nodemon is not recommended for command line applications

Answer (score 0):

I could be very wrong but try without equals = when passing the argument in the terminal like this.

```
    nodemon app.js read --title "to by"
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason console is only logging command result if I add yargs.argv somewhere in the page bellow the initializing command when using nodemon

```
const yargs = require("yargs");

yargs.command({
  command: "my_command",
  describe: "Some Thing is Happening!",
  handler: () => console.log("Command is Running."),
});

yargs.argv; // not storing value just mentioning.
```

with nodemon in scripts

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
```

You can use `npm start my_command`